# Binding Enable Property to BindingGroup.IsDirty

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have got a View who's DataContext is set to an Employee.
Further, the view uses a BindingGroup and Validation Rules.
At last the view has got 2 Buttons: Save and Cancel

Save: Validate the users input and in case of success, save the changes.
Cancel: Rollback the user input and restore the original values.

Until this point it works fine.

Now the last requirement and the problem:
For a better User Experience i would like to enable the save Button when the user begins to change data.
To achieve this, I bind the IsDirty Property of the BindingGroup to the Enabled Property of the Button.
Unfortunately it doesn't work. The binding seems to be correct, but the user interface does not recognize the change of IsDirty.

Who can i solve this problem?

My Model:

```
public class EmployeeModel:ModelBase
{
    private int _nr;
    private string _firstname;
    private string _lastname;


    public int Nr
    {
        get
        {
            return _nr;
        }

        set
        {
            _nr = value;
            OnChanged(nameof(Nr));
        }
    }

    public string Firstname
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstname;
        }

        set
        {
            _firstname = value;
            OnChanged(nameof(Firstname));
        }
    }

    public string Lastname
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastname;
        }

        set
        {
            _lastname = value;
            OnChanged(nameof(Lastname));
        }
    }

}
```

ModelBase:

```
public class ModelBase:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }
}
```

ValidationRule:

```
public class EmployeeValidationRule:ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        BindingGroup bindingGroup = (BindingGroup)value;
        if (bindingGroup.Items.Count == 2)
        {
            EmployeeModel employee = (EmployeeModel)bindingGroup.Items[1];

            string firstname = (string)bindingGroup.GetValue(employee, "Firstname");
            string lastname = (string)bindingGroup.GetValue(employee, "Lastname");

            if (firstname.Length == 0)
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Firstname can not be empty.");

            if (lastname.Length == 0)
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Lastname can not be empty.");

        }
        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }

}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    private EmployeeModel _employeeModel;

    public EmployeeModel Employee
    {
        get
        {
            return _employeeModel;
        }

        set
        {
            _employeeModel = value;
        }
    }

    public EmployeeViewModel()
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        //Employee = (from e in _context.Employee
        //            where e.Nr == 158
        //            select e).FirstOrDefault();

        Employee = new EmployeeModel() { Firstname = "Billy", Lastname = "Wilder" };
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        //_context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

At last the View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3_Validation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3_Validation"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3_Validation.ViewModel"
    xmlns:vr="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3_Validation.ValidationRules"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Employee" Height="250" Width="525" 
    Validation.ValidationAdornerSite="{Binding ElementName=lbErrors}" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:EmployeeViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.BindingGroup>
    <BindingGroup x:Name="MyBindingGroup">
        <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
            <vr:EmployeeValidationRule/>
        </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
    </BindingGroup>
</Window.BindingGroup>

<Grid x:Name="gridMain">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Nr:"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Employee.Nr}"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Vorname:" Target="{Binding ElementName=tbFirstname}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="tbFirstname" Text="{Binding Employee.Firstname}"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="Nachname:" Target="{Binding ElementName=tbLastname}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="tbLastname" Text="{Binding Employee.Lastname}"/>


    <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lbErrors" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor).(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
               Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold"/>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock  x:Name="tbIsDirty"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="IsDirty?" Click="btn1_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnSave" Content="Save1" Click="btnSave_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="btnSave1" Content="Save2" Click="btnSave_Click"  IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=MyBindingGroup, Path=IsDirty}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" Click="btnCancel_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyBindingGroup.BeginEdit();        // Not really needed?
    }   

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.BindingGroup.CommitEdit())
        {
            EmployeeViewModel vm = (EmployeeViewModel)this.DataContext;
            vm.Save();
        }
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BindingGroup.CancelEdit();
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tbIsDirty.Text = BindingGroup.IsDirty.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using `BindingGroup` correctly. But without a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do, it's not possible to say for sure. Please improve your question. Explain what specifically you want the code to do, what it's doing now, and why you think `BindingGroup` will help you achieve your goal.

Comment: I have rewritten the original post and added the complete code for my test-application. Hope it describes my intention and the problem better.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're trying to do. And I don't think it'll work. While `BindingGroup` inherits `DependencyObject`, I'm not sure why, as it doesn't have any dependency properties. And it doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. So when `IsDirty` changes, there's no way for the binding system to notice that. You'll need to approach the issue a different way.

Comment: FWIW, I haven't had to do this sort of thing much. But when I did, I wrote an attached property, to reference the validation rules attached to specific elements in the markup. I just had to provide a property to pass to the attached property, which returned that list of elements (e.g. text boxes, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that BindingGroup.IsDirty does not Implement INotifyPropertyChanged, it's not a useful source for this type of databinding.

Possible solution:
 - Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in the view
 - Creating a own IsDirty in the view, using INotifyPropertyChanged
 - Adding an event handler for KeyUp, which sets my IsDirty in case of BindingGroup.IsDirty.
- Binding of Enabled to the new Property

Disadvantage: Need if implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged in the view.

Advantage: It works.

CodeBehind of View:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }


    private bool _isDirty;

    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get
        {
            return _isDirty;
        }

        set
        {
            _isDirty = value;
            OnChanged(nameof(IsDirty));
        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyBindingGroup.BeginEdit();        // Not really needed?
        gridMain.KeyUp += GridMain_KeyUp;
    }

    private void GridMain_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.MyBindingGroup.IsDirty)
        {
            IsDirty = true;
        }
    }


    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.BindingGroup.CommitEdit())
        {
            EmployeeViewModel vm = (EmployeeViewModel)this.DataContext;
            vm.Save();
            IsDirty = false;
        }
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BindingGroup.CancelEdit();
        IsDirty = false;
    }

}
```

Further improvements:
Now i moved IsDirty to my ViewModel, so I don't have to implement INPC in the view. Another advantage is, that in this way, Commands can consume the property and finally i don't have to use databinding for the enabled Property, because i get it over the command.